# How to filter apache access logs on the basis of ips, domain and url?

Tags: linux, apache, shell

i have to filter out group of same ips , domain, and some url pattern and print output as well along with count, domain, and url pattern from my apache access logs.|
Currently i am using awk command but is shows only count and ip's not domain and url patterns.

**My input is**

```
Feb  2 03:15:01 lb2 haproxy2[30529]: "www.abc.com" 207.46.13.4 02/Feb/2020:03:15:01.668 GET /detail.php?id=166108259 HTTP/1.1 GET 404 123481 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "" ci-https-in~ ciapache ci-web1 0 0 1 71 303 762 263 1 1 -- "" "" "" ""

Feb  2 03:15:02 lb2 haproxy2[30530]: "wap.abc.com" 106.76.245.226 02/Feb/2020:03:15:01.987 GET /listing.php?id=1009 HTTP/1.1 GET 200 182 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; LG-K420 Build/LMY47V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36" "https://wap.abc.com/s.php?q=land+buyers" ci-https-in~ ciapache ci-web2 0 0 0 18 18 17813 219 0 0 -- "" "" "" ""

Feb  2 03:15:02 lb2 haproxy2[30531]: "wap.abc.com" 106.76.245.226 02/Feb/2020:03:15:02.067 GET /listing.php?id=6397 HTTP/1.1 GET 200 128116 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "" ci-https-in~ varnish ci-van 0 0 0 1 3 470 1001 0 0 -- "" "" "" ""

Feb  2 03:15:02 lb2 haproxy2[30531]: "wap.abc.com" 106.76.245.226 02/Feb/2020:03:15:02.067 GET /listing.php?id=6397 HTTP/1.1 GET 200 128116 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "" ci-https-in~ varnish ci-van 0 0 0 1 3 470 1001 0 0 -- "" "" "" ""
```

**Expected output**

```
count  ip             domain     url
2     106.76.245.226 wap.abc.com /listing.php?id=6397
1     106.76.245.226 wap.abc.com /listing.php?id=1009
1     207.46.13.4    www.abc.com /detail.php?id=166108259
```

currently i am using this command but it is not giving expected output

```
cat /var/log/httpd/access_log | grep www.abc.com* | awk '{print $7}' |  sort -n | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 50
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts which you have put to solve your problem. Could you please do add samples of input and expected output too and let us know then, it will help us to understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep www.abc.com* /var/log/httpd/access_log | awk '{print $7,$6,$10}' |  sort -n | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 50
```

use other columns as well in awk.